# Should I wait before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that questions that have accepted answer are usually avoided by users.

Does it mean that I should wait (like for a day) before accepting answers (even when they fully answer my question) so answering user can get more (deserved) up-votes therefore being rewarded for his input?

Comment: If your dilemma is: "should I attract unnecessary attention to my fully answered question when there are 9000 other questions that need answers today" then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's totally up to you.

There is a minimum wait time (15 minutes, or [48 hours on your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) before you can accept any answers. This is to allow the community *some* time to get the answers in, but generaly, the number of good unique answers after the wait time is low.

Once the wait time expires, feel free to accept the answer you think is best, whenever you feel like it, and *if* you want to.

Comment: 15 minutes to accept another answer. I would just like to add that upvotes will still come from people with a similar problem (if deserved). So feel free to accept what you want, when you want.

Comment: *but generaly, the number of good unique answers after the wait time is low* - this definitely varies based on question, though. The more specific and less generally known your question, the more likely it is someone with some specific knowledge will come along after someone has had a go.

Answer (score 0):

I usually wait at least 24 hours and sometimes longer before accepting an answer even if the initial answer is good.  This is because at any given moment 1/3 of the planet is probably asleep.  I also post questions on weekends when many people are probably away from their computer.  Waiting 24 to 48 hours gives more people a chance to see the question and respond to it before I accept an answer.  As I see it waiting benefits everyone.

The only downside to waiting that I can think of is if the first person to provide a good answer gets impatient and irritated and decides not to respond to my future questions erroneously thinking that I do not appreciate his or her effort.

Comment: I think the vast majority of answerers won't get annoyed if their answers aren't accepted instantaneously (I don't). If people post answers for the rep only they probably don't care about the quality of the answers anyway. On the other hand, why wait if an answer is spot on? It may discourage this weird type of answerers that just repeat a correct answer (it happens).

Answer (score 0):

I Think that if the answer works for you, you should accept it....