# Does deleting questions with negative vote undo the negative rep lost

Tags: support, reputation

- Let say for example I asked a Valid question from my side I got
  around 20 views and -5 votes for the question for which I will be
  losing 5 rep.
- Now if I delete the question do I get back the 5 rep lost or else rep
  lost do not come back.
- Agreed that the question might sound similar [to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254039/if-you-lose-rep-below-a-privilege-does-your-actions-in-those-areas-undo)

  few but I cannot ask/comment anything due to lack of rep so I ask another question here.
  Any advice accepted

Comment: Each downvote decreases 2 rep not 1

Comment: Be wary of deleting too many of your questions or answers. While the details are unknown, it is probable that such actions will contribute to a ban on being able to ask or answer questions.

Answer (score 9):

When you delete a question or answer you lose any rep gained and regain any rep lost from that question or answer.

- If the question was at -5 you'd regain 10 points.
- If the question was at +5 you'd lose 25 points.
- If the question was at +5/-5 you'd lose 25 - 10 = 15 points.

It's as if those votes had never happened.

Comment: @user285oo6 - what's that got to do with the question?

Comment: @ChrisF Can't I ask a question in a comment for this or do I need to ask another question for this

Comment: @user285oo6 - ask another question - but search first here and on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) to see if it's already been asked.

Comment: @user285oo6 The reason is mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255820/2982225).

Comment: @user285oo6 - "a while". There's a delay on certain rep updates to make it harder for anyone watching your rep to spot when you down-vote (for example). I assume that this comes under the same delay.